# Proof Dot Product and Cross Product of Complex Numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

I found this problem from Complex Variables book by Murray R. Speigel

I have a trouble to understanding this proof:

$$z_1\cdot z_2=\Re(\overline z_1 z_2)$$

And

$$z_1\times z_2=\Im(\overline z_1 z_2)$$

From my reference,

$$\overline z_1 z_2=(z_1 \cdot z_2)+i(z_1 \times z_2) \tag 1$$

When we have to proof $(1)$, we need dot and cross product definition

And it will use this following definition:

$$z_1 \cdot z_2=\frac{\overline z_1 z_2+z_1\overline z_2}{2}\tag 2$$

$$z_1 \times z_2=\frac{\overline z_1 z_2-z_1\overline z_2}{2i}\tag 3$$

Considering those are definition (not a theorem), it makes me confuse, then what is the idea behind $(2)$ and $(3)$?

Could you give me the best explanation?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want geometric interpretation or computational proof?

Comment: @edm if you have a lot of time, why not both? Or just one of them is fine. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can treat a complex number as a 2D real vector in the plane.

The definition $$z_1\cdot z_2=\Re(\overline z_1 z_2)$$
is just the same as dot product of two 2D real vectors $z_1,z_2$.

While the definition

$$z_1\times z_2=\Im(\overline z_1 z_2)$$

is the signed area of the parallelogram determined by the vectors $z_1,z_2$.

These two facts may not be obvious. By letting $z_1=a_1+b_1i, z_2=a_2+b_2i$, you can just calculate the following:

$$\Re(\overline z_1 z_2)=a_1a_2+b_1b_2=\text{the dot product $(a_1,b_1)\cdot(a_2,b_2)$}\\ \Im(\overline z_1 z_2)=a_1b_2-a_2b_1=\text{signed area of the parallelogram determined by $(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2)$}$$

If you are familiar with the properties of dot product and cross product of 2D vectors, it should be obvious that $$z_1\cdot z_2=z_2\cdot z_1\\ z_1\times z_2=-z_2\times z_1$$ so you can proceed to calculate $$z_1\cdot z_2=\frac{z_1\cdot z_2+z_2\cdot z_1}{2}=\frac{\Re(\overline z_1 z_2)+\Re(\overline z_2 z_1)}{2}=\frac{\Re(\overline z_1 z_2+\overline z_2 z_1)}{2}=\frac{\overline z_1 z_2+\overline z_2 z_1}{2}$$ because $\overline z_1 z_2+\overline z_2 z_1$ is already a real number (remember $\Re(w)+\Re(z)=\Re(w+z)$, and $\overline z+z$ is real); and also calculate $$z_1\times z_2=\frac{z_1\times z_2-z_2\times z_1}{2}=\frac{\Im(\overline z_1z_2)-\Im(\overline z_2z_1)}{2}=\frac{\Im(\overline z_1z_2-\overline z_2z_1)}{2}=\frac{\overline z_1z_2-\overline z_2z_1}{2i}$$because $\overline z_1z_2-\overline z_2z_1$ is completely imaginary ($\Im(w)+\Im(z)=\Im(w+z)$; $z-\overline z$ is always completely imaginary; for a completely imaginary number $z=bi$, $\Im(z)=\frac{z}{i}$).